# Remove white box around input range on firefox mobile

Tags: html, css, firefox, slider

I'm trying to customize a range slider. There's a lot of CSS, so I've tried to use a generator as a starting point: http://danielstern.ca/range.css/#/

This should be flat 2 colors (just the green), and it does look like that on Firefox desktop, Chrome desktop, and Chrome Mobile. But in firefox mobile:
[image]

It has this weird box around it. Any way to remove it?

EDIT:

here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/samkeddy/pen/pNxrdw

```
{}
```

what it looks like on desktop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK73W.png

and what it looks like when I open it on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUKtt.png

Comment: In the link you provided seems to look fine on firefox mobile. Maybe you should provide the code.

Comment: edited with codepen and screenshot